In Rails Administrate, how to change search bar from "like" to "equal"?
I use https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate to create my dashboard page
This is my attributes types
  ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    user_id: Field::Number.with_options(searchable: true),
    id: Field::Number,
    company_id: Field::Number.with_options(searchable: true),
    notes: Field::Text,
    created_at: Field::DateTime,
    updated_at: Field::DateTime
  }.freeze

With this configuration, if I search for user_id or company_id, it will find the matching ID ("like" on SQL condition). But I want an exact result ("equal"). How do I achieve that?
Anyone has ever done this before?

Unfortunately there is no existing functionality for that Search#query_template utilizes "LOWER(CAST(#{table_name}.#{column_name} AS CHAR(256))) LIKE ?" for every field.
